# varchar value presents as 0 in laravel livewire project

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, search, laravel-livewire

[Now solved by myself - see comment post. Leaving up in case this helps someone else in the future]

I have a laravel project in which I am using livewire for a live search box to present a dynamic lists of results from a mysql database for the field "song", also adding related "composer" field for those matches.

Even though both fields are correctly VARCHAR type, "song" is presented in the results as "0" (unless there's a number in the song title, in which case it presents just that number) and "composer" is properly presented as text.

I cannot figure out what is causing this issue - can you help?. I can tell that each result listed is accurate (because I know the composers associated with each song), but the song title is presented as 0.

Here is my code:

Model FILE: songs.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class songs extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'songs';
    protected $primaryKey = 'song';
```

Controller FILE: SearchSongs.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\songs;

class SearchSongs extends Component
{
     public $showresult = false;
     public $searchterm = "";
     public $fetchedresults;
     public $selectedsong;

     // Fetch records
     public function searchResult(){

         if(!empty($this->searchterm)){

             $this->fetchedresults = songs::orderby('song','asc')
                       ->select('song','composer')
                       ->where('song','like','%'.$this->searchterm.'%')
                       ->get();

             $this->showresult = true;
         }else{
             $this->showresult = false;
         }
     }


     public function fetchSongDetail($song = 0){

         $fetchedresults = songs::select('song','composer')
                     ->where('song',$song)
                     ->first();

         $this->searchterm = $fetchedresults->song;
         $this->selectedsong = $fetchedresults;
         $this->showresult = false;
     }

     public function render(){ 
         return view('livewire.search-songs');
     }

}
```

Blade component FILE: search-songs.blade.php

```
<div>

  <div class="search-box">
      <input type='text' wire:model="searchterm" wire:keyup="searchResult">

      <!-- Search result list -->
      @if($showresult)

              @if(!empty($fetchedresults))
                  @foreach($fetchedresults as $fetchedresult)

                      <li wire:click="fetchSongDetail('{{ $fetchedresult->song }}')">
                           {{ $fetchedresult->song }} - {{ $fetchedresult->composer ?? 'no composer' }}
                      </li>

                  @endforeach
              @endif

      @endif

      <div class="clear"></div>
      <div >
          @if(!empty($selectedsong))
              <div>
                   {{ $selectedsong->song }} - {{ $fetchedresult->composer ?? 'no composer' }}<br>
              </div>
          @endif
      </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I ran a die-and-dump to see what was being grabbed, and this is what it showed. Note that where it says "Song Title Text" this is a valid song title text. That there is null for composer is also correct for that song.

```
#items: array:56 [▼
    0 => App\Models\songs {#382 ▼
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "songs"
      #primaryKey: "song"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      +preventsLazyLoading: false
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
      #attributes: array:2 [▼
        "song" => "'Song Title Text"
        "composer" => null
      ]
      #original: array:2 [▼
        "song" => "Song Title Text"
        "composer" => null
      ]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #attributeCastCache: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      +usesUniqueIds: false
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▼
        0 => "*"
      ]
    }
```

I have tried selectRaw("CAST(song AS CHAR) AS song") but this made no difference.

Comment: I fixed it myself! I added this line to the database table Model file:

    protected $keyType = 'string';

This forced the key to be string, as it was showing as int in the dd() results.